# Not everything is sent properly to the user by kernel module

Tags: c, kernel, kernel-module

I' ve got such a function

```
static ssize_t read_mydevice(struct file *filp, char* buf, size_t count, loff_t* ppos) {

 char *text = "Device is empty\n";
    int len = strlen(text);


    if (*ppos != 0)
            return 0;


    if(count>bytesindev) count=bytesindev;
    if(bytesindev==0) {

        if (copy_to_user(buf, text, len))
                 return -EINVAL;
     } else {
        while(count>0) {
        if (copy_to_user(buf++, msg_Ptr, (unsigned long) 1)) {
                 return -EINVAL;
                } else {
                    strcpy(msg_Ptr, (msg_Ptr+1));
                    bytesindev-=1;
                    *(msg_Ptr+bytesindev) = '\0';
                }
                count-=1;
                printk(KERN_INFO "%d\n", count);
            }
            printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", buf);
     }
    /*
     * Tell the user how much data we wrote.
     */
    *ppos = len;

    return len;

 }
```

The problem is that user doesn't get whole message, it always is a first 13-16 signs of it, a loop is made so many times that it's supposed to. At first the third argument passed to copy_to_user was the length of whole message, but this solutions also didn't work properly. Any ideas?
This function should give the user a part of buffer he demanded (number of bytes first written to the buffer, a bit like a FIFO). Data must have been send earlier to the device. It's the function for writing:

```
static ssize_t
write_mydevice(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
if(bytesindev+len>limit) {
    if(limit-bytesindev<=0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Device is full.\n");
            return -EINVAL;
    } else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Device almost full.\n");
        strncat(msg_Ptr, buff, limit-bytesindev);
        bytesindev+=limit-bytesindev;
        return limit-bytesindev;
    }
} else {
    //printk(KERN_INFO "Device working\n");
    strncat(msg_Ptr, buff, len);
    bytesindev+=len;
    return len;
} 
}
```

Comment: Is copy_to_user() returning a number other than 0?

Comment: No, any errors doesn't appear, but I think they should when returned value is other than zero (return -EINVAL)

Comment: What is the value of `limit`? Depending on `limit` value you may have an off-bye-one overflow as `strncat` always writes the null character.

Comment: limit is 2048 and I wrote there about 30 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that read function returns wrong value, it always returns length of text, not the lenght of the sended message.

Answer (score 2):

The intent of the code is not completely clear to me, but there is at least one problem.  The strcpy call is not valid.  It is not guaranteed to work with overlapping buffers:

```
strcpy(msg_Ptr, (msg_Ptr+1));
```

It may have the intended result, but it is undefined behavior.  See [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)

Comment: I want to move the data in buffer to it's beginning, I tried to do it using a for instead but nothing changed.

Comment: Even if this isn't causing the problem it is highly suspicious because it is dealing with memory (pointers) and its behaviour is undefined

Comment: @WojciechReszelewski:  You can use memmove for overlapping sections of memory.

Comment: May the size of buf be a problem? I'm testing this module using cat command. It looks strange for me, becouse I know that the loop performs for every character typed it, but later they don't appear on the screen.